# Firebase get data ionic4

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Can not get data from returning object. I can get class from firebase realtime database but all attributes still undefined. 
But if i user console.log() there are not undefined anymore.

```
constructor(public alertController: AlertController,
                private userService: UsersService,
                private apartmentService: ApartmentService) {
        this.userService.currentUser().then(
            (user) => {
                if (user) {
                    this.currentUser = user;
                    console.log(this.currentUser); // defined
                    console.log('Apartment Key = ' + this.currentUser.apartmentKey); // Undefined
                    if (user.apartmentKey !== null && user.apartmentKey !== '') {
                        this.apartmentService.getApartment(this.currentUser.apartmentKey).then((apartment) => {
                            if (apartment) {
                                apartment.users.forEach(value => {
                                    this.userService.getUserByEmail(value).then(userByEmail => {
                                        this.users.push(userByEmail);
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Firebase Index is on 'email"

```
 "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,    
     "my-users": {
        ".indexOn": "email"
   }
  }
```

and the service method to get user

```
async getUserByEmail(email: string): Promise<User> {
        const user: User = new User();

        this.fireBase.database.ref(Path.USER_PATH)
            .orderByChild('email')
            .equalTo(email)
            .once('value')
            .then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.forEach(dataSnap => {
                    if (dataSnap) {
                        const data = dataSnap.val();
                        user.email = data.email;
                        user.apartmentKey = data.apartmentKey;
                    }
                });
            });

        return user;
    }
```

This is console output:

[image: This is console output]

Answer (score 1):

While you've declared `getUserByEmail` as `async`, you're not returning a promise.

```
async getUserByEmail(email: string): Promise<User> {
    const user: User = new User();

    return this.fireBase.database.ref(Path.USER_PATH)
        .orderByChild('email')
        .equalTo(email)
        .once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach(dataSnap => {
                if (dataSnap) {
                    const data = dataSnap.val();
                    user.email = data.email;
                    user.apartmentKey = data.apartmentKey;
                }
            });
            return user;
        });
}
```

So the top-level now returns the result of the promise that `once()` returns, which in turn then returns your user.